# Where are the missing TCP packets?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I observed a surprising thing that when there are both udp-based and tcp-based applications sending packets, if the upd-based application sent the packets so fast that the bandwith are nearly filled with udp packets, then the tcp packets would be very hard to send out.

The surprising thing is that though tcp-based application is able to send a few packets out (observed by the return value of write()), the receiver of the tcp packets never receives them. Why? Is that because the tcp-packets arenot finally sent out by the network card? or the tcp packets are actually dropped by routers?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the return value of write() is not an indicator of whether packets were sent. It just indicates that the data was buffered.

Second, if you are saturating the network with UDP packets there will be a lot of packet loss, and TCP being adaptive will adapt to that by sending packets out more slowly. If the packet loss gets too high TCP can basically stop altogether. The solution is not to saturate the network with UDP packets.

Answer (score 0):

*This is a simplified answer. There are many articles you can read up on.*

UDP is a layer built upon IP. Ditto for TCP. The network card just sends out IP packets. You can look up the various structures for these packets.

TCP is a protocol that uses IP packets but uses a mechanism to try to ensure delivery and rearranges packets in the correct order. See the article on Wikipedia.

Routers are free to drop packets. This can occur when the network is overloaded, network connections are down or the IP packet is corrupted.

So to answer your question their is no preference between UDP or IP to be transmitted from one end to the other.